# Solve the Poisson equation $\Delta f = x_2$ in the unit disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Let $D$ be the disk of radius 1 centered at (0,0). Find a formula for the solution of

$\Delta u=f$ in $D$

$u=1$ on $\partial D$

In the case where $f(x)=x_2$

In polar coordinates $f(r,\theta)=rsin(\theta)$

Supposed to use separation of variables to solve, but I guess I don't really understand how to do that.

Comment: Can you write down the differential equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: It may help (a lot) if you describe what your variables are... for example what are $u$ and $x_{2}$?

Comment: Added a bit more to problem, I am trying to find a solution like $u(x_1,x_2)= something$ or even just in polar coordinates $u(r,\theta)=something$

Answer (score 1):

When asked to solve $\Delta u = f$ with a polynomial function $f$, it's feasible to get some solution $p$ (without regard to boundary conditions) just by trying a polynomial of degree $\deg f+2$. What polynomial $p$ has 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x_2^2} = x_2\quad ? 
$$
... I think a multiple of $x_2^3$ will do the job.

Then you are left with the task of finding a harmonic function with boundary value $x_2-p(x_1,x_2)$, which will not be hard if you use the identity (valid on the boundary) 
$$
x_2^3 = \sin^3\theta = \frac14(3\sin\theta-\sin(3\theta))
$$